# CakePHP3 associated entities not coming through from find() (or get) even with contain clause

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, model-associations

[edit]  solved, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32638610/221650

Some associated data is not coming through, although it's in the `contain` clause.

I can get `$project->Participants` if I set a `belongsToMany` relationship in the `Projects` table, relating to `Participants` through `ProjectParticipants`, but that way I still can't reach other tables associated with `ProjectParticipants` even with `$project->participants->_joinData->other_related_table`

How would I do to get `ProjectParticipants` and `Participants` with the same query?

Code:

```
// Database: Projects <--1:N-- ProjectParticipants --M:1--> Participants

// ProjectController:
    $project = $this->Projects->get($id, ['contain'=>[
            'ProjectParticipants.Participants']);
// ProjectsTable:
    $this->hasMany('ProjectParticipants', [
        'foreignKey' => 'project_id']);
// ProjectParticipantsTable:
    $this->belongsTo('Participants', [
        'foreignKey' => 'participant_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very complicated many to many relationship.

```
//projectTable
$this->belongsToMany('Participants');

//praticipantsTable
$this->belongsToMany('Projects');
```

It's well explained in the [Bookmark Tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html).

Comment: But I already mentioned the `belongsToMany` relationship in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's working fine, I hadn't noticed there was a custom `Entity\Project::_getParticipants()` that was returning a Collection.
A simple debug on that object showed everything alright, but then when running it through a foreach, the associations disappeared.